Running several instances of headless libreoffice: where's race?
I'm running libreoffice (headless) to make several hundreds of pdfs from odts. It's too slow, so I've tried to run some in parallel.
SOME pdf files are generated without any error but with zero size. Running one libreoffice at a time, I never hit it; running two, often.
I've tried to run it as recommended with custom UserInstallation and in separate directories like
/usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/oo.44978" --headless --convert-to pdf /tmp/oo.44978/046rEQ1Nee.odt --outdir /tmp/oo.44978

Which resulted in 100% corruption.
I've even tried to use different sockets
/usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --nofirststartwizard --accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=53668;urp;" "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/oo.53668" --headless --convert-to pdf /tmp/oo.53668/xaKag8N_3d.odt --outdir /tmp/oo.53668

With the same result
Where's a race condition in libreoffice and how do I evade it?
LibreOffice 7.6.4.1
FreeBSD 13.2-RELEASE

 -env:SingleAppInstance="false" fails as well

why are you commenting on your own question ... please edit the question, instead of writing a comment

What @jsotola said. Any and all updates and improvements to your question NEED to be made in the question itself. Making your question better and more complete is a good thing and is strongly encouraged. Use the EDIT button to do that.
